# Stored procedure for inserting the new records in the table from data table

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, datatable

I am getting an error while creating the below stored-procedure which would  insert the new records in the table  from the data table

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Cde_SecureList_Upsert]
    @SecureList SecureList READONLY,
    @ListType varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@ListType='FETCHDETAILS')
        SELECT * FROM TBL_TICKETING_ALTERNATE_CREDIT_CARD_LIST
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO TBL_TICKETING_ALTERNATE_CREDIT_CARD_LIST([CardRefID], [KEY], [MIS_Field1], [MIS_Field2], [ValidatingCarrier]
            , [OtherCarriers], [Card Vendor], [Card], [Expiration], [Precedence], [AlertEmail], [maxTktAmt], [IRP_remark]) 
            SELECT [CardRefID], [KEY], [MIS_Field1], [MIS_Field2], [ValidatingCarrier]
            , [OtherCarriers], [Card Vendor], [Card], [Expiration], [Precedence], [AlertEmail], [maxTktAmt], [IRP_remark] FROM @SecureList;
        END
    END
GO
```

Error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_Cde_SecureList_Upsert, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 60]
Invalid column name 'CardRefID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_Cde_SecureList_Upsert, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 60]
Invalid column name 'MIS_Field1'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_Cde_SecureList_Upsert, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 60]
Invalid column name 'MIS_Field2'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_Cde_SecureList_Upsert, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 60]
Invalid column name 'ValidatingCarrier'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_Cde_SecureList_Upsert, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 60]
Invalid column name 'OtherCarriers'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_Cde_SecureList_Upsert, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 60]
Invalid column name 'Card Vendor'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_Cde_SecureList_Upsert, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 60]
Invalid column name 'Card'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_Cde_SecureList_Upsert, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 60]
Invalid column name 'Expiration'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_Cde_SecureList_Upsert, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 60]
Invalid column name 'Precedence'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_Cde_SecureList_Upsert, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 60]
Invalid column name 'AlertEmail'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_Cde_SecureList_Upsert, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 60]
Invalid column name 'maxTktAmt'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_Cde_SecureList_Upsert, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 60]
Invalid column name 'IRP_remark'.

Completion time
```

which is strange since the column names are correct

Below is the screenshot of my SP and header/columns of the table wherein I am trying to insert the data from the data table

[SP and table column details screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0OWn.png)

If I do select * from the data table

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Cde_SecureList_Upsert]
    @SecureList SecureList READONLY,
    @ListType varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@ListType='FETCHDETAILS')
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TBL_TICKETING_ALTERNATE_CREDIT_CARD_LIST]
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[TBL_TICKETING_ALTERNATE_CREDIT_CARD_LIST](CardRefID, [KEY], MIS_Field1, MIS_Field2, ValidatingCarrier
            , OtherCarriers, [Card Vendor], Card, Expiration, Precedence, AlertEmail, maxTktAmt, IRP_remark) 
            SELECT * FROM @SecureList;
        END
    END
GO
```

I am getting an error as

```
Msg 120, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_Cde_SecureList_Upsert, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 60]
The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.
```

Comment: What error are you getting. How is this being used in C#?

Comment: @MintMoney . . . The error message seems pretty clear.  One (or perhaps both) of `TBL_TICKETING_ALTERNATE_CREDIT_CARD_LIST ` or `@SecureList` doesn't have those columns

Comment: If you see my screenshot(the last section), the TBL_TICKETING_ALTERNATE_CREDIT_CARD_LIST has all these columns, and the data table is passing these values from the C# code.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Any inputs?

Comment: You are getting this error because your table has more or less columns than your insert statement and you are using a * to select from your table. While there is nothing wrong with using a *, it is a better practice to specify the column by name to prevent errors in the future when the table is modified.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have anything to do with C# so you should remove the tag from your question. Could you provide the error message?